# Cplex: license not found or unreadable

Tags: matlab, cplex

I am using the trial version of ILOG CPLEX studio from IBM. So, I tried using the cplex solver in a matlab script for my optimization problem and it told me:

CPLEX: license file not found or unreadable.

I tried checking the whole IBM forum for solutions but while I saw them talking about license for academic initiative version. I didn't see anything relating to license in the trial version. Please, do I need a license for the trial version? If yes, how do I get that? or did I miss something during setting it up?

P.S. Matlab sees CPLEX and Yalmip sees cplex too but during run, it says it cant see the license.

Thank you.

Comment: Cplex itself is running without any license issues?

Comment: Yeah. It runs on itself without demanding licence